# Sql Server Express Installation

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-express

I am learning ADO.NET programming. I want to install Sql Server Express for doing the some programs. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate on my windows 7 home basics 64 bit.

I have downloaded Sql Server Express 2008 and tried to install it, but I am not able to install it properly (the process completes with some errors). Please help me  — do I need another version of Visual Studio or should I install Sql Server *prior* to Visual Studio?

Comment: SQL Server Express installation should be completely independent from Visual Studio installation. What exactly does "I am not able to install it properly" mean? Any error messages?

Comment: What errors did you see?

Comment: Please post the errors.  For all we know, the error say "The setup files are corrupt." Or "You are doing it wrong!"

Comment: You should have had an option to install SQL Server Express with your Visual Studio 2010 installation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you attempt the installation *as an administrator*.  There is an issue with the Sql Server installer where it can fail if you don't explicitly choose to run the installer as an administrator.  Just being logged in on an account with Administrator privileges isn't good enough.

Comment: not really. I have no problem installing SQL Server on my Window 7 machine under my own account.